# OpenLaszlo drag and rotate issue

Tags: openlaszlo, lzx

I have written one sample code for rotating and dragging a view. Both are working properly in openlaszlo swf runtime but it's not working as is in DHTML runtime.

In both OL 4.9 and in openlaszlo 5.0 i see that there is a small displacement. I have attached a git hub link

https://github.com/karthick6891/cvs/tree/master/rotateanddrag

Can any one tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: That's a bug in the LFC, when using non-zero offset values for views, based on my experience.

Comment: @raju-bitter: Any work arounds?

Comment: You already have the math to calculate the rotation based on the mouse pointer position, just add the values for x and y offset to it.